# errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):

Tags: angular, angular-providers

Am having this error on my chatservice i can't solve it
   [Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUPUt.png)

here is the actual code  of my chatservice

```
import{Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
export class chatService{
    private url = 'http://localhost:8000'
    private socket:any;

    sendMessage(message:string){
        this.socket.emit('add-message', message);
    }
    getMessages(){
        let observable = new Observable(( observer:any)=>{
            this.socket = io(this.url);
            this.socket.on('message',(data:any)=>{
                observer.next(data);
            });
            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            }
        })
        return observable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow! As per the rules, "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." Please include the actual code in the question. Images of code aren't good for several reasons, the most important being we can't copy your code in order to try it for ourselves, so finding the error or recreating your issue becomes very difficult, whereas you could make it easier for us by simply including all info in the actual question.

Comment: seems you have not added `chatService` as provider in your module? Also consider using `ChatService` instead of `chatService`, just as a sidenote, not related to problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, as per the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-04), you should use a capital letter for your service (aka. `chatService` => `ChatService`)
2. Next, did you include `ChatService` as a provider in your application's module file?

   ```ts
   @NgModule({
       providers: [
           ChatService
       ]
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks. that was it i didn't know